# Commerce 2 Subscription Prices

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, plugin-craftcommerce2

We've currently got Subscriptions setup on a site which works a charm, but my main issue is outputting the price of the subscription, after the user has subscribed.

From the docs/templates I can even see how this is possible?!

You can get it via:

```
{% set subscriptions = craft.subscriptions.user(currentUser) %}

{% for subscription in subscriptions %}
    {{ subscriptionPlanData.plan.amount }}
{% endfor %}
```

But if for example, the plan is `£300.00` then it outputs as `30000` and when formatted, it comes out like `30,000.00` using `{{ subscriptionPlanData.plan.amount|number_format(2, '.', ',') }}`

I can't see anyway of showing the user, how much they've paid in a human format without hacking around the number.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Stripe [stores the amount in cents](https://stripe.com/docs/api#balance_transaction_object-amount). If you want to format it from the `subscriptionPlanData.plan.amount` variable in your template you would need to divide by 100 first.

```
{{ (subscriptionPlanData.plan.amount / 100)|currency }}
```

Answer (score 2):

I could be wrong here as I've not used subscriptions with Commerce yet, but using the filter `|currency` worked perfectly for me when outputting the correct format after having tried `|replace` and `|number`.

Comment: I thought that might have worked, but sadly it still just output `£30,000.00` :(