# Commerce Subscription Prices

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, stripe, commerce-subscriptions

I need to be able to output the price of a subscription after the user has subscribed. I'm using the Stripe Gateway. This post indicates to use `{{ subscriptionPlanData.plan.amount }}` but that doesn't seem to work for Commerce 3.

[Commerce 2 Subscription Prices](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/27976/commerce-2-subscription-prices)

The code below works but only after you refresh the payment history for the subscription in the admin, which seems to be a manual task.

```
{% set payments = subscription.getAllPayments() %}
      {% if payments %}
           {% for payment in payments %}
                ${{ payment.paymentAmount|number_format(2, '.', ',') }}
           {% endfor %}
      {% endif %}
```

Any idea how to get that payment history to automatically refresh after a subscription? Since that includes taxes, etc. that might be the best solution?

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
{{ subscription.subscriptionData.plan.amount }}
```

to get the price of the plan the customer subscribed to.

That returns in cents so you'll need to convert and format it.

```
{{ (subscription.subscriptionData.plan.amount / 100) | currency('USD', stripZeros=true) }}
```